# Skyshard/Sky Crystal Farming

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Are there any good or known farming spots for [Skyshard](http://www.wowhead.com/item=86547#dropped-by) to drop? I have spent several hours farming the Mogu in the Vale of Eternal Blossoms in an attempt to get the ten Skyshards needed to craft the [Sky Crystal](http://www.wowhead.com/item=86546). I currently only have one of them and came from the mogu during my farming. I do now for a fact that some mobs change/disappear depending on the dailies that are available that day. So my question is: Where is a good farming spot in Vale of Eternal Blossoms with minimal downtime between mobs.

Comment: So far, every "good" method get nerfed as it's discovered.

Comment: Every mob in Vale of Eternal blossom has an equal chance of dropping it. So I guess whereever there are more mobs available to kill would be a good place to 'farm' for it? Again this is different depending on the time of the day and the server you are on with everyone and their dog doing dailies there.

Comment: I received one in a Treasures of the Vale, and two from drops, on my way to Exalted. This will be a _very long grind_.

Answer (score 1):

The Shao-tien Marauders, Soul-Renders, and Stonebark Tricksters have the best chance of dropping it - about 1 in 300 chance (0.3%). There is a large cluster of these in the north of the Vale around 36, 24. If you can AoE them down... that might be your best shot.

Good luck, it'll be a hell of a grind. I'm exalted with Golden Lotus on two toons and only get one drop!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said - no real 'good' spot.  Where and what you are doing is probably the best you can hope for.  I did the GL dailies everyday until I reached exalted and never got a single drop, and as far as I know only a couple other members of my guild have even gotten a single drop.

The mogu in the daily area are probably the your best bet.

I have a feeling that with the next chapters of the expansion they will drop more or be a drop from a dungeon/raid boss. Which may also be a possibility, but again have never seen one drop in a heroic or LFR.